# Laravel, Passing parameters with routes via controller (Work for get but not working for post)

Tags: laravel, api, parameters, controller, routes

I'm using laravel, and I need to pass parameters via routes to controller. Passing them with get is working, but passing a parameter with post is not working...

I have the following routes

```
Route::get('/ticket-read/{id}', ['uses' => 'TransactionController@show']);

Route::post('/ticket-create/{id}', ['uses' => 'TransactionController@insertTransaction']);
```

and here are the controller functions:

```
public function show($id){
  echo $id;
}

public function insertTransaction($id){
  echo $id;
}
```

Problem: the get method works correctly, while the post method is not working and it leads to the following error:

```
 C:\Laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php

            if ($request->method() == 'OPTIONS') {
                return (new Route('OPTIONS', $request->path(), function () use ($methods) {
                    return new Response('', 200, ['Allow' => implode(',', $methods)]);
                }))->bind($request);
            }

            $this->methodNotAllowed($methods);
        }

        /**
         * Throw a method not allowed HTTP exception.
         *
         * @param  array  $others
         * @return void
         *
         * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
         */
        protected function methodNotAllowed(array $others)
        {
            throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);
        }

        /**
         * Get routes from the collection by method.
         *
         * @param  string|null  $method
         * @return array
         */
        public function get($method = null)
        {
            return is_null($method) ? $this->getRoutes() : Arr::get($this->routes, $method, []);
        }

        /**
         * Determine if the route collection contains a given named route.
         *
         * @param  string  $name
         * @return bool
         */
        public function hasNamedRoute($name)

Arguments

    ""


Environment & details:
GET Data empty
POST Data empty
Files empty
Cookies
XSRF-TOKEN  

"eyJpdiI6InBtSGhBWVQ4UElxVGlaeDJnM1lZaWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoia3ZYTXEyUDRPeG5cL0pNeGZ6aWFhSlVBZDZkSkFLZHB1akhRWG5FUTZLWmhGSWVpQ2JROWI2em5VaUpiXC9sUnMxazhMQkRXNUZFUjJF ▶"

laravel_session     

"eyJpdiI6IlpwSXdneTc3NThwSDJMTUZFdlUrM1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiMDdDNHROYnpoTlhzTTFOUlRQbmVcL0V4bHFsbnRGMXUxWGlcL3VnaVlIVGcrWjBteGJoaW9vclE1ZFwvWWphNlNkU0RlclwvSUFQblhw ▶"

Session empty
Server/Request Data
DOCUMENT_ROOT   

"C:\Laravel\public"

REMOTE_ADDR     

"127.0.0.1"

REMOTE_PORT     

"27644"

SERVER_SOFTWARE     

"PHP 7.1.9 Development Server"

SERVER_PROTOCOL     

"HTTP/1.1"

SERVER_NAME     

"127.0.0.1"

SERVER_PORT     

"8000"

REQUEST_URI     

"/ticketCreate/3"

REQUEST_METHOD  

"GET"

SCRIPT_NAME     

"/index.php"

SCRIPT_FILENAME     

"C:\Laravel\public\index.php"

PATH_INFO   

"/ticketCreate/3"

PHP_SELF    

"/index.php/ticketCreate/3"

HTTP_HOST   

"127.0.0.1:8000"

HTTP_USER_AGENT     

"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0"

HTTP_ACCEPT     

"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"

HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    

"en-US,en;q=0.5"

HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    

"gzip, deflate"

HTTP_COOKIE     

"XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InBtSGhBWVQ4UElxVGlaeDJnM1lZaWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoia3ZYTXEyUDRPeG5cL0pNeGZ6aWFhSlVBZDZkSkFLZHB1akhRWG5FUTZLWmhGSWVpQ2JROWI2em5VaUpiXC9sUnMxazhMQ ▶"

HTTP_CONNECTION     

"keep-alive"

HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS  

"1"

REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT  

1518694286.8524

REQUEST_TIME    

1518694286

Environment Variables empty
Registered Handlers
0. Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler


note that it shows me the following message: REQUEST_METHOD     "GET", while I'm using post in the Route, so what it should be the reason?
```

Comment: I'm quite new to Laravel, but here's a couple of things you can try. You can try to use `Route::match(['get', 'post']), ['uses' => 'TransactionController@show']);` and see if that works. - - - And it looks like (from this line: `return new Response('', 200, ['Allow' => implode(',', $methods)]); }))->bind($request);` that the post-request returns an empty response that is attempted to be imploded, which fails because it's empty. So perhaps try and change the `post`-route to echo something like: `echo 'Response: ' . $id;`, to see if it give another error. I hope this helps

Comment: I tried it, and it's not working even if I echo a simple text only without $id. with respect to the match I didn't understand how to use it! get and put are both pointing to same function in this case, and this will not help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the return you are doing inside of your controller, try something like this:

```
public function insertTransaction($id){
   return response()->json(['id' => $id], 200);
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the same error still exists!

Comment: Can you screenshot your request and give us the image where we can see headers and payload

Comment: I edited my question, and appended the whole request data, you can note that it shows the request as a get method althoug I'm using post. I think here is the problem, but still need help to fix it.

Comment: You are sending a request badly, show us the piece of code where you make that request

Comment: No code, I'm simply using a browser to test it, and here is the url: 127.0.0.1:8000/ticket-create/2 ( Note that when change post to get in the route, it works fine...)

Comment: Every call you do from a browser is a get call, to do POST call you need postman or you gotta do it via ajax